# How to still be able to click on the cell of dataGridView even when you have a picturebox on the cell?

Tags: c#, datagridview, picturebox

I have a dataGridView where I display the production process. On the right cell of the dataGridView that is called `Is Roll Ready`, I make the visibility of the combobox which offers `Yes` and `No` options (i.e. I created when initializing) when this cell is clicked.

[image]

If `Yes` is clicked, I create a pictureBox with a tick image and if `No` is clicked I create a pictureBox with a cross icon like below:

[image]

[image]

Once the cell is clicked I assign my global `PictureBox picture` to the `pictureBox`that is added to the clicked cell and I make use of `Click()` event of pictureBox to make the combobox visible when the pictureBox (hence the cell) is clicked. Below is my `CellClick` event for the datagridview:

```
  private void CompletedMachines_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == -1) return;
            if (CompletedMachines.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.CompareTo("MachineNr2") != 0 && CompletedMachines.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.CompareTo("TimePassedSince") != 0 &&
                 CompletedMachines.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.CompareTo("NrOfLinesPerCm2") != 0 && e.RowIndex > -1 && CompletedMachines.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.CompareTo("HeightOfLamallae2") != 0)
            {
                
                PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
                picture = pictureBox; //assign the newly created pictureBox to the global one              CompletedMachines.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
                cellRect = CompletedMachines.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
                comboBox.Size = new Size(cellRect.Width, cellRect.Height);
                comboBox.Location = new Point(cellRect.X, cellRect.Y);
                comboBox.Visible = true;
                pictureBox.Size = new Size(cellRect.Width, cellRect.Height);
                pictureBox.Location = new Point(cellRect.X, cellRect.Y);
                pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                pictureBox.Click += PictureBox_Click; //call the Click event
            }
        }
```

PicutreBox `Click` event:

```
   private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            comboBox.Visible = true;
        }
```

However, when I have multiple rows in the dataGridView, every time this `PictureBox_Click` event is called, the combobox appears on the cell that owns the latest added picturebox. This is because I assign the global picturebox `picture` to the latest added one.

Is there a way to still make use of `CellClick` event of the dataGridView even if a custom control is added on the cell so that I do not have to use `PictureBox_Click` event? Or any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reference to ComboBox in PictureBox.Tag.

```cs
// When creating PictureBox
pictureBox.Tag = comboBox;
```

And then use `sender` in event handler to get PictureBox and ComboBox:

```cs
private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var comboBox = (ComboBox)((PictureBox)sender).Tag;          
  comboBox.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: In which event handler I use the `sender` ?

Comment: You can fetch `PictureBox`: `var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;` and then use its location as source for comboBox: `comboBox.Location = pictureBox.Location;`